# remove network discovered printers in cups web page

Tags: linux, printer, cups, raspbian, raspberry

I am trying to remove network discovered from cups webpages. I am working on a cloud print service and run a raspbian bulleyes. I will have to deploy my system to customers and I want to remove every printer discovery. Printers will only have a local installation from an engineer.
I have tried to configure cups browse protocols and stuff.
I have tried to disable and stop avahi daemon and socket. Put ipv4 and ipv6 into avahi conf.
Weird situation, systemctl disable avahi.socket re-enable it at reboot.

Whatever I do, there are still a bunch of discovered printers displayed.
Any idea to remove them all ?

Thank you.